# Extracting text from an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: linq

I have a `IEnumerable<T>` collection with Name, FullName and Address.

The Address looks like this:

```
Street1=54, Street2=redfer street, Pin=324234
Street1=54, Street2=fdgdgdfg street, Pin=45654
Street1=55, Street2=tryry street, Pin=65464
```

I want to loop through this collection and print only those Names, FullNames whose Street1=54

How can i do it in LINQ?

Ok I was able to do this to extract Street1 of the Address

```
coll.Address.Split(",".ToCharArray())[0]returns me Street1=54 .
```

Now how do I add this to the condition and print only those Name, FullName whose Street1=54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update, you can adapt Jared Par's code this way:

```
var result = collection.Where(x => x.Address.Contains("Street1=54"));
foreach ( var cur in result ) {
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", cur.Name, cur.FullName));
}
```

If you want to be able to plug in your Street1 value with a variable, then do this:

```
var street1 = "54";
var result = collection.Where(x => x.Address.Contains("Street1=" + street1 ));
foreach ( var cur in result ) {
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", cur.Name, cur.FullName));
}
```

BTW, you really should update your question or add a comment to a specific answer rather than adding a new answer that isn't.

Comment: Can I do something like this?
var result = collection.Where(x => x.Address.Contains("Street1=" + street1 )).OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Length);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var result = collection.Where(x => x.Address.Street1==54);
foreach ( var cur in result ) {
  Console.WriteLine(var.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the correct list of :

```
IList<T> matches = myListOfEnumerables.Where(m => m.Street1 == 54).ToList();
```

Then loop and print.

Comment: If all you're going to do is loop forwards through the results once, you don't need IList, and so you don't need .ToList(). See JaredPar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the record looks like this:

```
{Name="Jan" FullName="Kathy Jan" Address="Street1=54, Street2=redfer street, Pin=324234"}
```

I have to loop through this collection and print only those Names, FullNames whose Street1=54

Answer (score 0):

If the updated information is accurate, you should change the way you store the data.

It looks like you've packed the address information into a string. Why not store it as an object. In fact, why not just as more fields in the same object as the Name and FullName? (and why duplicate the first-name information?)

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName, LastName, Street1, Street2, Pin;
}

IEnumerable<Person> persons = GetAllPersonsSomehow();

foreach (Person person in persons.Where(p => p.Street1 == "54"))
    Console.WriteLine(person.LastName + ", " + person.FirstName);
```

Assuming you have to keep the address information in a string, you need a parser for it.

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetAddressFields(string address)
{
    return address.Split(',').ToDictionary(
                s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('=')).Trim(),
                s => s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') + 1).Trim());
}


foreach (Person person in persons.Where(p => 
                GetAddressFields(p.Address)["Street1"] == "54")) 
    Console.WriteLine(person.LastName + ", " + person.FirstName);
```

Comment: Can I do something like this?

var result = collection.Where(x => x.Address.Contains("Street1=" + street1 )).OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Length);

Answer (score 0):

So, what you could do is that you could write a generator for parsing the Address field and then enumerating properties of that. This is a fairly common thing in the functional programming world.

To be fair you would want this code to be lazy in that it would only compute a minimal set. I'm gonna suggest some code from the BCL but you can (and probably should) rewrite the same helper methods with generators.

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> NameValueSplit( this string s )
{
    foreach (var x in s.Split(','))
    {
        var y = x.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2, StringSplitOptions.None);
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(y[0].TrimStart(), y[1].TrimEnd());
    }
}
```

With that helper function you can write code like this

```
var result = collection.Where(x => x.Address
    .NameValueSplit().Any(x => x.Key == "Street1" && x.Value == "54"));
foreach ( var item in result ) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Now this code will not run on your SQL Server if you were thinking of that, but you could write a WHERE clause where you would search the Address field for a sub string %Street1=54%. I like lazy evaluation for string operations and think that's a lacking feature in the BCL. That is why I suggested that kind of solution.